# Override with lambda syntax

Tags: c#, lambda, roslyn, c#-6.0

Consider the following expression:

```
public override string ToString() => "ABCDEFG";
```

compiles to this:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return "ABCDEFG";
}
```

despite this syntax being syntactic sugar, I would have expected `ToString()` to equate to `Func<string>`

```
Func<string> ToString = () => { return "ABCDEFG"; };
```

Notice that `Func<string>` requires a `return` statement, but the lambda syntax for the `ToString()` override does not.

Why does Lambda syntax for overrides not require the use of `return`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Firstly, it's *not* a lambda expression - it's just that expression-bodied members (introduced in C# 6) also use the syntax of `=>`. They *don't* involve creating a delegate instance or an expression tree though.

As for why `return` isn't needed - it isn't needed in lambda expressions either, when they're expression-bodied lambda expressions:

```
Func<string> toString = () => "ABCDEFG";
```

That's been true ever since lambda expressions were introduced in C# 3, and is by far the most common case in LINQ, e.g.

```
var query = strings.Where(x => x.Length > 3)
                   .Select(x => x.ToUpperInvariant());
```

Comment: I never knew you could do that!

Comment: Did you mean to write _"Jisi calls it alpha-4"_? It seems like an accident. P.s. I cannot wait for C# in Depth 4th edition!

Comment: @Petrichor: Sorry, no - that was a copy/paste fail. No C# in Depth 4th ed in the works, I'm afraid. May do one for C# 7.

Comment: @JonSkeet - can I clarify, is there a difference between Lambda syntax and a Lambda expression? - and therefore can expression bodied functions be described as using Lambda syntax, or would that be confusing?

Comment: @series0ne: That would still be confusing, IMO - one would naturally expect to use lambda syntax in a lambda expression. The two syntax elements just use the same token (`=>`).

Answer (score 3):

This new C# 6 feature is called *expression-bodied function member*. While it does indeed look like a lambda expression it is none as it doesn't evaluate to an expression. As you already stated it is merely syntactic sugar for the compiler.